# how to read xml from FTP server in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. Please tell me that how to retrieve and read XML file which is placed on ftp server in Javascript. Javascript only speaks HTTP and WebSockets (on newer browsers), and not FTP

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, be precise and ask your question with the code you have tired or add more information to discuss.  This is not a right way to ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  To ensure you get A: an answer and B: a good answer, please ensure you provide information about what you have tried as well as some code.  It's difficult to answer a question about programming not knowing the language/context/expected results/current issues/etc when a question is vague like this.  Many people will just read it and move on if they do not have a good place to start answering!

Comment: You could at least have googled.

Comment: ofcourse i have googled and see some code but dont find answer for ftp server thats why i have asked my question here  DanFromGermany. but if  anybody is not understanding my question then i i amgoing to add some more information.

Comment: I have asked question here after alot of search i have studied methods to retrieve from remote host using XMLHttpRequest and many others but don't understand for ftp because javascript does not supports ftp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to using client-side JS, it's not possible. It is possible with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org), though.

Comment: I want to retrieve xml in javascript. is there not any way to retrieve file in javascript??

Comment: Not through ftp. Use http and you will be fine. Also, here is an xml parser http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about client side `Javascript` (the one that is in the browser), then this is not possible (it can understand only `HTTP` protocol and with the rise of `HTML5` also `WebSockets`). `FTP` is completely another protocol and hence this is not possible.

Think about it this way: your JS is stored in your browser. So the whole code that will connect to your FTP and do something there is exposed to everyone. In order to connect to FTP you need to provide your credentials (your username and password). This means that everyone who wants to get them can get them. This is not nice :-).

As I understand, the thing you want to achieve - user does something on your site (click a button) and he can download the file from the ftp. In this case I would do something like this. On click I will make an `ajax call` or some sort of redirect ( `window.open('http://yourserver/getFile.php');` ) And the script in getFile.php (php does not matter here - this is any server side script python, asp, ...) connects to your FTP server and does whatever you want.